# How to access parameters from other fuction C++?

Tags: c#, c++, c, c++11, visual-c++

Well the problem is that I'm using PostgreSQL in it's C/C++ Interface and I'm trying to access parameters from other function in the same Class, I want to use this parameters in This public method *W.exec()* to enter the strings to an DB.

First of all I'm using all as objects and all are **public**.

*Connection.cpp* In the function **wInsert**.

```
int Connection::wInsert() {
  try {
    connection c(stringConnection);
    if (c.is_open()) {
      work W(c);
      int size = sql - > size();
      /*string name,lastname;
      cout << "Name";
      cin >> name;
      cout << "Last name";
      cin >> lastname;
      W.exec(this->insert(string name,string lastname));*/
      W.exec(this - > insert(name, lastname)); // here is where I call the function **insert**
      cout << "Opened database successfully:" << endl;
      W.commit();
    } else {
      cout << "Can't open database" << endl;
      return 1;
    }
    c.disconnect();
  } catch (const std::exception & e) {
    cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Between the comment lines I tried to pass the variables directly and it worked,but I'm trying  to do this since the *main().* as parameters that recieve a function.

In my *main()* I ask for these strings.

```
Database * db;
string name, lastname;
cout << "Name\n";
cin >> name;
cout << "Last name\n";
cin >> lastname;
bd - >insert(name, lastname);
```

Then in *Connection.cpp*. In the function **insert** Is where I try to pass this values that I received from the main to the **W.exec()** in **wInsert**. I tried to convert my ***int Connection::wInsert()*** to ***string Connection::wInsert(string name, string lastname)*** but I got an error because *PostgreSQL* need this to be **int** to work properly.

So, I also looked for convert an int to string but I think this totally different or use the ***malloc*** function but I'm no sure how to implement that in this code.

```
char * Connection::insert(string name, string lastname) {
  sql = new string("INSERT INTO person(name,lastname)"\
    "VALUES (\'" + name + "\', \'" + lastname + "\');");
  int size;
  size = sql - > size() + 1;
  char * query = new char[size];
  strcpy(query, sql - > c_str());
  return query;
}
```

Comment: There is no official C++ interface. What are `connection` and `work`?

Comment: @molbdnilo `Connection` is my class and `work` is for Create a transactional object.

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at this. I think you need to use $1,$2 and bind the parameters to your precompiled statement

[How to prepare statements and bind parameters in Postgresql for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833322/how-to-prepare-statements-and-bind-parameters-in-postgresql-for-c)